# Add formhandler field data to subject

Tags: typo3, typoscript

My goal is to have the Formhandler log UID inside the Admin emails subject.
Inside of my email template I'm using
`###value_tx_formhandler_log_inserted_uid###` to insert a unique id.
I need to get this value into my Admin emails subject. E.g.

```
"Order ID: ###value_tx_formhandler_log_inserted_uid###"
```

I've read various forum posts, each do something different and I ended up with this snippet:

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings.predef.form {

    # TEMPLATE MARKERS
    name = Form1
    templateFile = typo3template/typo3/ext/formhandler/form1/default.html

    markers {
        name = TEXT
        name.value = Form1
    }

   finishers {
     1.config {
         class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_Mail
         subject = TEXT
         subject.value = ###GP:tx_formhandler_log_inserted_uid###
     }
   }  
[...]
```

which just yields "{$formhandler.admin.subject}" as the subject.

I also tried other variations like
`###LLL:tx_formhandler_log_inserted_uid###` or `tx_formhandler_log_inserted_uid`
The backend field "subject" is empty.
Pasting the HTML placeholder into the backend field didn't work either.
I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I got it working.
First of all, I **forgot to specify** that I want to **configure the admin mail.**
Adding `admin {` fixed the problem of getting only `{$formhandler.admin.subject}`.

The UID value itself can be accessed with `GP:formhandler|tx_formhandler_log_inserted_uid` 
I combined that with the noTrimWrap as suggested by [@bernd-wilke-πφ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6796354/bernd-wilke-%cf%80%cf%86)

**The final snippet looks like this:**

```
finishers {
     1 {
        class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_Mail
            config {
                admin {
                    subject = TEXT
                    subject.data = GP:formhandler|tx_formhandler_log_inserted_uid
                    subject.noTrimWrap = |Order number: ||
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In what way can you access the id you want to insert?

From the notation `GP:tx_formhandler_log_inserted_uid` I would assume a GET/POST value.
For using this value in typoscript you need to do it like this (or similar: dataWrap):

```
subject = TEXT
subject.data = GP:tx_formhandler_log_inserted_uid
subject.noTrimWrap = |Order ID: ||
```

The notation `LLL:tx_formhandler_log_inserted_uid` would be a language specific text (you would also insert by `.data`) but it would be a static text for each language.

Comment: I tried to use 'subject.data = GP:tx_formhandler_log_inserted_uid' but that still results in '{$formhandler.admin.subject}' in the mail subject. I'm not shure its actuall a get/post parameter. A quick google search yields no results on that either

Comment: Checking the chrome dev tools, the value in question does not seem to be part of the Query string parameters.